# gcloud snapshot created in region, not zone, when executed from cron job

Tags: google-compute-engine, snapshot

Trying to fire off a gcloud snapshot from a cron job on a ubuntu compute-engine.  When executed from an ssh session:

```
gcloud compute disks snapshot disk-1 --zone=us-west1-b --snapshot-names=${snapshot-name}
```

creates a snapshot with the given name in zone "us-west1-b"

However, the same statement issued from a cron job creates the snapshot in **region** "us"

Can anyone explain this and how to get the snapshot created in the desired zone?

Not sure if this matters or not, but the vm is in us-west1-b (Oregon), so the cron job executes from that zone.  I am in Montana, so probably am considered in us-west3 (Utah) when executing the command from ssh.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots#selecting_a_storage_location), a disk snapshot can be created in a Region or a Multi-region. It can't be created in a Zone.

By default the snapshot location is chosen automatically based on the source disk location: it is created in a nearby multi-regional location closest to the region of the source disk. Neither the VM location nor account location affect the default location of the snapshot. `gcloud` command line parameters `--region=REGION` and `--zone=ZONE` define a region and a zone of the source disk, and don't influence the snapshot location too.

In the initial question the snapshot location is not specified. The source disk `disk-1` is located in the region `us-west1`. Therefore its snapshot is created in the [default location](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots#default_location) that is a Multi-region `us`.

You can specify the snapshot location with the `gcloud` command line parameter [`--storage-location=LOCATION`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/disks/snapshot#--storage-location) that is the [Cloud Storage multi-region](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/bucket-locations#location-mr) (`us`, `eu`, `asia`) or the [Cloud Storage region](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/bucket-locations#location-r) (like `us-central1`, `us-east1`, `europe-west1`, `asia-west1`, etc).

Comment: Thanks, I mis-read the documentation.

Comment: ok, now I still don't understand; it complains about the --region and --storage-location arguments:  gcloud compute disks snapshot my-disk --region us-west1 --storage-location us-west1 --snapshot-names=snap-01 --csek-key-file=/home/me/keyfile.json produces the errors: unrecognized arguments: --region us-west1 --storage-location us-west1

Comment: apparently the documentation is wrong.  It accepts --zone as an argument, but not --region; and it does not accept --storage-location.

Comment: If the disk `disk-1` was created as Zonal (with the GCP Console option `Replicate this disk within region` unset), the command `gcloud compute disks snapshot` needs the `--zone` parameter to specify the source disk location.